# upload images with lightning:inputRichText

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, community, richtextarea

I'm not sure if I am just completely missing something or no one asks this question but I can't find a solution to this. I have a requirement to be able to upload images into the body of a rich text field which is being used to facilitate back and fourth communication in a SFDC community <> console.

[image]

I've built a lightning app which works well except I can't figure out how I'm supposed to upload images into the field. Is `lightning:inputRichText` even capable of doing so? There is no documentation that says it doesn't and it's supposed to replace the legacy `ui:richText` field (which does not allow for local import anyways). I've also tried the `CKEditor` approach and that also does not support local import, not to mention with locker service enabled it does not render.

I'm totally stumped, any help is appreciated.

**Here is my component in case it helps:**

```
    <aura:component controller="caseCommentsController" implements="force:appHostable,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">

  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <aura:attribute name="comments" type="Case_Comments__c[]"/>
  <aura:attribute name="newComment" type="Case_Comments__c"
         default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Case_Comments__c'
                       }"/>
  
    <!-- display case comments -->
    <div class="container slds-p-top--medium">
        <div id="list" class="row">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.comments}" var="comment">
                <c:caseCommentsList comment="{!comment}"/>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>   
    </div> 

    <!-- input form using components -->
    <div class="container slds-p-top--large">
        <form class="slds-form--stacked">
            <div class="slds-form-element">
                <div class="slds-form-element__control">
                    <!-- ui:inputText aura:id="caseid" disabled="true"
                               value="{!v.newComment.Case__c}"/ -->               
                </div>
            </div>
         <div class="slds-form-element">
           <div class="slds-form-element__control">
             <lightning:inputRichText aura:id="addComment" 
                                      disabledCategories="FORMAT_FONT"
                                      placeholder="Add a comment..."
                                      value="{!v.newComment.Comment__c}"/>                              
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-form-element">
            <ui:button label="Add Comment" 
                       class="slds-button slds-button--neutral"
                       labelClass="label"
                       press="{!c.createComment}"/>
          </div>    
    </form>
  </div><!-- ./container-->
          
</aura:component>
```

Comment: lightning:inputRichText doesn't support upload from local files yet. You could upload the file to the record as a content file using a lightning:input component, as (sort of) described here: http://peterknolle.com/file-upload-lightning-component/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try copying and pasting the image?
I am in similar scenario - the image is pasted Ok, but the lightning page renders just with the link of the image instead of actually showing the image.
I don't think the **attach** option to upload image is not available on `lightning:inputRichtext` yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file input field in addition to the `lightning:inputRichText`. Handle file upload with JS controller and add the base64 of the image to a `<img>` `src` attribute. Then finally append this `<img>` element to the end of the `lightning:inputRichText` value. Doing this the uploaded image will appear at the end of the rich text.

**Lightning component:**

```
<lightning:input name="file1" type="file" label="Add image" multiple="false" accept="image/png" onchange="{! c.handleFilesChange }"/>
<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.richtextvalue}" />
```

**JS controller:**

```
handleFilesChange : function (component, event, helper) {
    var files = event.getSource().get("v.files");
    if(files){
        var file = files[0]
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            var template = component.get("v.richtextvalue");
            if(template===undefined) template = '';
            template += '<img src="'+reader.result+'"/>';
            component.set("v.richtextvalue",template);
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
    }
},
```

**Note that when saving this richtextvalue to a richtext field on an object, sf will take your base64 src and convert it to a url pointing to the image which they saved to documentforce.com This url is sadly not publicly accessible and will return a 404 when used outside your salesforce org. So thread carefully.**

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the code below

```
<lightning:inputRichText variant="bottom-toolbar" value="{!v.myVal}" placeholder="Type something interesting">
        <lightning:insertImageButton/>
</lightning:inputRichText>
```

This should give the upload image within the rich text

Comment: It doesn't work.